# JS Call global function inside function`s function

Tags: javascript, function

Please advice, I am trying to call the a() function inside of a function of b()`s function

I dont know how to link this a() function.

```
  d = function() {
         this.a = function() {}

         this.b = function() {
            x.hover(function() { this.a() });
         }
  }
```

Comment: !!,sorry I am a noob. Did not know that, removed tag...

Comment: You need to store a reference to `this` inside your `d` function. `var me = this;` then `me.a();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
d = function(){
     var self = this;

     this.a = function(){};
     this.b = function(){
        x.hover(function(){ self.a()  });
     }
}
```

In JS `this` is set depending on how a function is called, and within the anonymous function you pass to `x.hover()` it is not what you might expect. Simply keep a reference to the right `this` and use that...

Further reading: [MDN's `this` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried, but it didnt work..Please advice where should i check further? i set a alert(); before and after runing self.a(); alert went through before but not after.

Comment: @ShinanTillTominaga Can you post a fiddle with your code?

Comment: I maybe found my problem. Thank you very much!!!!